# In which variable is the model instance stored in customized view?

Tags: flask, flask-appbuilder

How can I actually pick up values from my model in a customised template?

Let's assume for this example, the model for Request has an attribute "title".

Following views.py:

```
class RequestModelView(ModelView):
    datamodel = SQLAInterface(Request)
    extra_args = {'my_extra_arg':Request}
    show_template = 'show_request.html'
    list_columns = ['title','description','request_status']
```

and here the show_requests.html

```
{% extends "appbuilder/general/model/show.html" %}

    {% block show_form %}
        This Text is before the show widget
        {{ super() }}
        This Text is shown below..
        <hr>
{{ (self.title) }}; {{pk}}; {{pk['title']}}

    {% endblock %}
```

In which variable can I find my object?
The only parameter that works is `{{pk}}` (it shows the ID of the Request).

I was thinking of something like `item['title']`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A very similar question was asked on their [Github](https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder/issues/513#issuecomment-310139615). I think you would have to use something along these lines:

views.py

```
class RequestModelView(ModelView):
    datamodel = SQLAInterface(Request)
    list_columns = ['title','description','request_status']
    add_template = 'show_request.html'

    @expose('/show_request', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    @has_access
    def show_request(self):
        get_filter_args(self._filters)
        self.extra_args = {'item': list_columns}
        return super(RequestModelView, self).add()
```

show_requests.html:

```
{% extends "appbuilder/general/model/show.html" %}

    {% block show_form %}
        This Text is before the show widget
        {{ super() }}
        This Text is shown below..
        <hr>
    {{ item['title'] }}

    {% endblock %}
```

Documentation is certainly not very clear in this aspect, but please check [template-extra-arguments](https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html?highlight=extra_args#template-extra-arguments)

I'm not sure if you would still need `extra_args = {'my_extra_arg':Request}`.

Comment: thanks for the hint. But it does not work ("jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'item' is undefined"). As self_extra_arg, did you mean {'item': self._filters} ? (as it was used in the git question)

Answer (score 0):

The following example should make things clear:

```
from .models import cars

beautiful_names = ["John", "Jane", "Bob"]
flowers = ["Aster", "Buttercup", "Roses"]

class IndexView(View):
    template_name = "dashboard/dashboard_index.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        all_car_objects=cars.objects.all()
        return render(request,
                      self.template_name,
                      context={"my_addresslist": beautiful_names,
                               "my_rose_list": roses},
                               "all_cars":all_car_objects)
```

In your template you can then do something like:

```
    <h1>Beautiful Names</h1>    
    {% for name in my_addresslist %}
      <p>{{ name }}</p>
    {% endfor %}

    <h1>Roses</>
    {% if my_rose_list %}
        {% for rose in my_rose_list %}
            <p>{{ rose }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    <h1>Cars</>
    {% if all_cars %}
        {% for car in all_cars %}
            <div>
                <p>{{ car.name }}</p>
                <p>{{ car.make }}</p>
                <p>{{ car.model }}</p>
            </div
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

So for your example, it comes down to this:

```
class MyView(ModelView):
    datamodel = SQLAInterface(MyTable)
    extra_args = {'my_request_list':Request}
    show_template = 'show_request.html'
```

```
    <h1>Requests</>
    {% if my_request_list %}
        {% for request in my_request_list %}
            <p>{{ request }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have already tried to pass in the Request object, but it is not a recordset, and returns "TypeError: 'ModelDeclarativeMeta' object is not iterable"

Comment: I put `request` there because it is in the case you presented. If "request objects" throws an error you should look into that. But your question is about getting those values in your template. The examples provided show you how to achieve that. The code provided to you works. May I suggest you try passing basic objects first. Make sure your view works and you understand how to present your models in the template. After  that, then pass the  more complex stuff to your template.

Comment: About your snippet. It is unclear what you are trying to achieve with the following part: datamodel = SQLAInterface(Request) and subsequently passing Request as my_extra_arg. This does not seem correct.